# Animating Hair along their path

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes, masking

I would want to try to achieve this kind of animation but i am not sure how to proceed. what i am interested in is the "follow path of the hair particles"

Any help or advice on how to proceed would be awesome!
Full animation: https://www.instagram.com/p/BsJ05RWHBV8/

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily using `Falloff Tracer` node.
Falloff Tracer is available on [Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/0hbbbc/) addon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! I am really new to animation nodes and I am having a hard time to understand how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Particle Instance Modifier might be your friend.
I used it once to make water droplets fall down wet hair. It's hard to see because the droplets are a little too transparent and the GIF is really bad quality, but they're there!

[image]

(see original complete HD video: https://youtu.be/1kSnauxiZqY).
[image]

You tell your particles that they should sprout in the hair system of your choice, how many of them, and where along the hair shaft do they go - and you can animate any of these sliders (see how they move with the animation). They will stick to the hair even if it moves.

How it works: [image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to model each hair as a separate curve (you could probably have a decent result with most of the curves being duplicates), adding a cylinder with curve deform modifier, setting the object origin to one end and then animating the scale of the object (along one axis). Similar approach would be to add an array modifier and animating the count.
[image: scale up]
[image: scale down]
[image: the mesh]
notice, that the mesh has to have a lot of loopcuts for this to work
With the array modifier, it would look the same, just instead of animating the scale, you would animate the count and the mesh would be just really short cube (/cylinder)
I would think there is better approach, but I am not sure what it is.